# Evaluating a tensor of type $(1,k)$ at arguments

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $A$ a smooth tensor field of type $(1,k)$. For $X_1,\dots,X_k \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ define $$A(X_1,\dots,X_k)(p) := A_p(X_1\vert_p,\dots,X_k\vert_p)$$ for $p \in M$. This is a rough section, i.e. a mapping $A(X_1,\dots,X_k): M \to TM$. Now I want to show that this rough section is a smooth vector field if and only if $A$ is smooth. So let us pick a chart $(U,\varphi)$ on $M$. Then we can write $$A = A^i_{j_1\dots j_k}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\otimes dx^{j_1}\otimes \dots \otimes dx^{j_k}$$ I know, that tensors of type $(1,k)$ are isomorphic to the mutlininear maps from $V^k \to V$, but I am stucked in evaluating $$A_p(X_1\vert_p,\dots,X_k\vert_p)$$ i.e. $$A^i_{j_1\dots j_k}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\otimes dx^{j_1}\otimes \dots \otimes dx^{j_k} (X_1\vert_p,\dots,X_k\vert_p)$$ May someone guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write locally $X_i = R_i^j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$ for some smooth functions $R_i^j$ where $1 \leq i \leq k$ and $1 \leq j \leq \dim M$. Then

$$ \left( A^i_{j_1,\dots,j_k} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} dx^{j_1} \otimes \dots \otimes dx^{j_k} \right) \left( X_1, \dots, X_k \right) = A^i_{j_1,\dots,j_k} dx^{j_1}(X_1) \dots dx^{j_k} (X_k) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} =\\
A^i_{j_1,\dots,j_k} R_1^{j_1} \dots R_k^{j_k} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}. $$

Assume that you know that this expression is a smooth (local) vector field for all smooth vectors fields $X_1,\dots,X_k$. Fix some indices $r_1,\dots,r_k$. By letting $R_i^j = \delta^j_{r_i}$ we see that the expression above is equal to

$$ A^i_{j_1,\dots,j_k} \delta^{j_1}_{r_1} \dots \delta^{j_k}_{r_k} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} = A^i_{r_1,\dots,r_k} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}. $$

Since this is a smooth vector, we get that the coefficients $A^i_{r_1,\dots,r_k}$ are smooth for all $1 \leq i \leq \dim M$. Since $r_1,\dots,r_k$ were arbitrary, this shows that the local coefficients of $A$ are smooth functions and so (this actually depends on your definitions) $A$ is smooth. In the other direction, it is clear that if all the coefficients are smooth then the resulting vector field is smooth as the coefficients of the resulting vector field are sums of products of smooth functions.